# Mac OS X 10.8.4 cacerts default password

Tags: macos, java

Yesterday I upgraded my Mac to Mac OS X 10.8.4, along with it came an update of the Java JRE (version 1.6.0_45). I want to add a certain CA to the list of trusted CAs by issuing

```
sudo keytool -keystore /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -alias mycertificate -import -file the-ca-certificate.der
```

I am prompted to enter the keystore password. Until the day before yesterday the default keystore password was "changeit", but now "changeit" won't work anymore. I tried to find information about the changed default password with google, but no success.

Does someone of you know the new default password for the system wide Java keystore on Mac OS X 10.8.4 with Java 1.6.0_45?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Adding a CA certificate to the system wide keystore is a legitimate way of trusting a custom CA.

Comment: A guess might be that this question appears to have nothing to do with professional systems administration; instead it appears you are talking about your personal computer. Which is not on-topic according to the [faq].

Comment: On my Mac (10.8.4, Java 1.6.0_45) the password is "changeit". Unlikely, but could it be that `keytool` requests the CA certificate password instead? In any case you can recover `cacerts` from backup...

Comment: Thanks, I somehow managed to corrupt the keystore file. Restoring it from backup did the trick.

Comment: Also ensure that it is not the SUDO password being asked for.

Comment: @sweetfa Your comment hit the bullseye in my case. It would be worth an extra answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also ensure that it is not the SUDO password being asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I managed to corrupt the keystore file. Restoring it from backup did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The password for java keystore is: 'changeit'

Comment: The OP already said the default no longer worked.